# Google Cloud Endpoints in Android Studio: how to generate Endpoints class in a different package

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

One of the Google examples for building a java backend on Google App Engine which is accessed through Cloud Endpoints is to be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/MobileShoppingAssistant-sample

The backend module in the sample app is organized with the following packages:

com.google.sample.mobileassistantbackend.models —> Includes the Entity files

com.google.sample.mobileassistantbackend.apis —> Contains Endpoint files that expose REST APIs

In Android Studio you can automatically generate the Endpoints from the Entity classes. But by default an Endpoint class is generated in the SAME package than the Entity class.

QUESTION:

How can I configure Android Studio in such a way that from a class in the "models" packages the Endpoint class is generated in the "apis" package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question.  Currently there is no way to specify that but there should be.

In the meantime you can simply move the generated endpoint to your desired package after generation.